# Simple Webservice that outputs JSON

Tags: web-services, json, installation, nsurlrequest

I want to build a simple web service that outputs JSON to test a parser on iPhone.

I have considered using public apis like twitter etc but I want to use a custom JSON text for a small proof of concept test.

I am using a MAC with Apache. 
I got the web server up and I can access an HTML page saying Hello World from 127.0.0.1
Can someone guide me as to how can I modify the HTML such that when I post a NSURLRequest, all I get back is JSON text. Not JSON in HTML/XML but plain JSON text. 
Something like -http://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.json

Any leads much appreciated.

Thanks
Dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it right here - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7k-suIGS_1k

Just in case some one else is looking for the same thing.